# What does this specification mean --> Graphics card and monitor capable of 800x600?

Tags: system-requirements

Well, I want to use 11.04. I guess, my laptop has got a monitor size comfortably over 800X 600. But it doesn't has a graphics card.
My configuration is:

Processor:  Intel Core Duo Processor T2080 (1.73 GHz)
Chipset:    Intel 945GM
Operating System:   DOS
Cache:  2 MB L2 Cache
Memory: 512 MB RAM
Hard Disk Drive:    80 GB 5400 rpm HDD
Optical Drive:  DVDRW/CDRW
Wireless:   802.11 abg
Display:    15.4"WXGA TFT
Video:  Shared as per Intel GMA950
Modem:  56 kbps
Network Card:   10/100 mbps
Ports:  4 USB 2.0, S Video Out, IEEE 1394, Headphone, Mic in, VGA, RJ11, RJ45, Kensington Lock Slot
Others: Bluetooth, 5 in 1 media card reader (SD, MMC, MS, XD,SD Pro).
Carry Case: Yes
Battery (backup):   6 cell
Warranty:   1-year CCI warranty

So will I be able to download and use Ubuntu 11.04?

Answer (score 2):

Your video chipset is listed as an [Intel i945GM](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/highlights/graphics/945gm/), that should work fine in 11.04.